# Understanding connection of $=$ and $>$ relations in proofs.

Tags: geometry, logic, proof-explanation

I would like to ask about a certain pattern I see in some proofs. This is an example taken from the book: Lang, Serge & Murrow, Gene. "Geometry - Second Edition" (p. 69)

> 10. An obtuse angle is an angle which has more than 90°. Prove (in a sentence or two) that a triangle cannot have more than one obtuse angle.

> **Proof**: Suppose triangle ABC has two obtuse angles, $\angle A$ and $\angle B$.
> $m(\angle A) + m(\angle B) > 180°$ contradicting the theorem that the sum of angles in a triangle equals 180°. Therefore, no triangle can contain two obtuse angles.

Is $=$ relation sometimes taken as the negation of $>$ relation ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: The opposite of $>$ is $\le$.

Comment: Two statements don't have to be negations be incompativle.   If Lucy is a lizard, then Lucy is not a lion.  But if Lucy is not lion that doesn't mean she is a lizard.  If $A+B > 180$ then $A+B \ne 180$.  But if $A+B \ne 180$ that doesn't mean that $A+B > 180$.  There is also the possibility that $A+B < 180$.....  But.. do you really not see the contradiction?  If $A + B > 180$ then $A+B$ *can't* be *equal* to $180$.  Surely that doesn't need explaining, does it.

Comment: Okay, actually this proof is packing quite a bit into a single (but to me utterly obvious line).  If $\angle A$ and $\angle B$ are obtuse then $\angle A + \angle B >90 +90=180$.  But $\angle C > 0$ so $A + B +C > \angle A + \angle B > 180$.  But the three angle of a triangle *must* be $A+B+C = 180$.  So our conclusion $A+B+C >180$ contradicts that $A+B+C=180$.  So a triangle can not have two obtuse angles.... Could you maybe elaborate what seems odd to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$=$ and $>$ are incompatible.  But that does not mean they are negations of each other.

If $a =b$ then $a < b$ and $a > b$ are impossible.

If $a>b$ then $a= b$ and $a< b$ are impossible.

If $a < b$ then $a=b$ and $a > b$ are impossible.

If $m \angle A + m \angle B > 180^\circ$ then $m\angle A + m\angle B =180^\circ$ is impossible.

You don't need a negation to do a proof by contradiction.

Suppose you want to prove Lucy is not a lion, and you manage to prove that Lucy is lizard.  Being a lizard means Lucy can't be a lion. So you are done.  QED. But if Lucy is not a lion that doesn't mean she is a lizard.  There are more than two options.  But those two options, being a lizard and being a lion, are incompatible.

Comment: Thank you, @fleablood. What you are saying is understandable. It seems obvious on the surface, but I would like to know what's going on from a logic standpoint. You gave me a clue; is it related with _trichotomy law_ ? For example, if $a = 9$, then $a < 9$ and $a > 9$ are impossible.

Comment: Depending on your text the trichotomy law is that given $a,b$ exactly on and only one of the following are true $a < b, a = b, b < a$ ($a >b$ is usually defined as $b < a$).  So if $A+B=180$ then $A + B >180$ is impossible (as is $A+B < 180$).  So if a triangle has two obtuse angles then $A+B > 180$ then $A + B + C >180 + C > 180$ so $A+B+C >180$ which contradicts that $A+B+C = 180$.

Comment: Thank you, @fleablood. That's **exactly** what I wanted to know. I appreciate it.

Comment: One little question, if you don't mind. On the justification of: $180 < C + 180$. Are you adding $180$ to both sides of the inequality $0 < C$ ? An axiom says that given $a, b$ and $c > 0$, $a + c < b + c$. Instantiating $c$ with 180, $a$ with $0$ and $b$ with $C$. Is this what you are doing ?

Answer (score 1):

$P\not>Q$ or $P\leq Q$ is the negation of $P>Q$.

$P=Q$ simply implies that $P>Q$ is false, but does not constitute a negation.

Answer (score 1):

As we have $\neg (\forall x \in A)P(x) = (\exists x \in A) \neg P(x)$, then $\neg (\forall x \in A)(x >a) = (\exists x \in A) \neg (x >a) = (\exists x \in A)(x \leqslant a)$. So finding $x$ such as $x=a$ can be take as counterexample for $x>a$, but is not its logical negation.

In stated case is used so called proof by contradiction
$$\left[(\neg P \Rightarrow Q) \land (\neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q ) \right] \Rightarrow P $$
$P$ is "amount of obtuse angles x = 1". It's logical negation  $\neg P$ is "$x < 1 \lor x>1$", but in proof is used only part of it $x>1$.

$Q$ sentence is "sum of angles = $180^\circ$", which we consider as true, so implication with $Q$ at end is always true i.e. $(x>2) \Rightarrow  Q$ is true. So proof reduced to $(x>2) \Rightarrow \neg Q$ which you have above.

Comment: Thank you. Helpful to see your logical equivalences. However, I cannot see the clearly where is the counterexample taking place. Could you give me a little more detail? I start with $m \angle A + m \angle B + m\angle C = 180^\circ$ (Theorem); how would you show the counterexample ?

Comment: You must have an intermediate step. $A + B + C =180$ and $A+B+C > A+B$ and $A+B > 180$.  By transitivity $A+B +C > 180$.  So you have both $A+B+C =180$ *AND* $A+B+C > 180$.  Surely you see that is a contradiction?

Comment: @F. Zer. I added answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for expanding the answer.